# Get log severity statistics from Lombok / @slf4j / Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j, lombok

I am using Lombok's `@Slf4j`annotation to get a `org.slf4j.Logger` instance in my Spring Boot classes like so:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class Blah {
    public void blupp() {
        log.info("Hi guys.");
    }
}
```

Because I cannot get hold of the log files easily, I want to provide an API in the application that returns "log temperature" i.e. a count of log messages of severity >= `ERROR` since last call.

Question: Is there an easy way to extend the Spring Boot / Lombok / Slf4j frameworks with a piece of code that will maintain the map Severity -> Count in memory?

Comment: probably change the question header to say "log statistics" instead of temperature? Seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975614/warnings-count-in-slf4j

Comment: I was thinking that "log temperature" is a carved term but this does not seem to be the case. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: This is no duplicate of the question linked above because I am asking specifically for Slf4j.